# how to get current ID in mvc4?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

is there is  away to get current Id of something in my mvc4 application
i've picture class model like

```
1- PicId -int
2- PicPath  - string
```

and i want to get current pictureId in this view and other views ?

Comment: could be @Model.PicId

Comment: and please post your view and tell us in which context you wish to use PicId

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass you Picture Model to View from Controller directly or via ViewModel.
Than you may call it as you wish:

```
<img src="@Url.Content(Model.PicPath)" id="@Model.PicId">
```

Comment: that's all ,so i don't need any thing to write in picture controller or other controllers ?

Comment: @Sonic No. As I mentioned, you need to pass Picture model from controller to View. There are a lot of ways to do it: ActionResult, ViewBag, Session ....